# How do I proceed with a fall detection sensor?

Tags: accelerometer, mpu6050, gyroscope

I am working on a human fall detection system using accelerometer and gyroscope which raises alarm in case of a fall. In all the papers I have read people have used net acceleration magnitude and compared it with a threshold and coupled it with change in orientation to detect fall. My question is would it be better to use acceleration in z-axis(normal to earth's surface) and compare it to threshold as compared to net acceleration as it might reduce false positives as net acceleration can exceed threshold in case of running but that won't happen if i take only acceleration in z-axis. Is my approach right?

[How can I implement sensor fusion using a gyroscope and a magnetometer to find the orientation?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/how-can-i-implement-sensor-fusion-using-a-gyroscope-and-a-magnetometer-to-find-t)

Comment: When's the last time you had something fall right along its Z axis?

Comment: What i meant was that using gyroscope values i will try to get the acceleration in original axis.And i wish to use that z-axis values.Rotating the axis.

Answer (score 1):

Find the derivative of acceleration over time, also known as [**jerk**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29). Falling will have a specific jerk pattern, whereas normal shaking and banging will have a completely differrent pattern.